# Full text search with codeigniter and xammp

Tags: codeigniter, full-text-search, xampp

I've been looking around for a while for full text search servers applets… I've found Sphinx (it worked for a while, until development was moved to mac, then everything fell apart; then I've looked into Solr; but couldn't get this thing to work with phpmyadmin.

Any advice about a well integrated **Full text search** that works well with **codeigniter** on **xammp**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solr and sphinx is an external service to your php,mysql,apache trio, the integration is pretty much as good as you make it. On osx, [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) might help you along the installing compiling steps.

You can also take a look into the [mysql's built-in fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), has less features than solr or sphinx and doesn't support innodb tables, but it doesn't require you to maintain an external service.